# Change locale with full calendar Jquery Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am playing with full calendar and I need change the locale.

When I try to do it. I get an error.

What script do I have to add to get rid off the error?

Chrome dev - error:

```
pt-br.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'datepickerLocale' of undefined
```

I have used:

html:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

JS:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/locale/pt-br.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.print.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        locale: 'pt-br'
    })

});

</script>
```

Comment: try loading the locale file *after* loading fullcalendar itself

Comment: Thank you Pekka, This solved my problem.

Comment: No problem. I added an answer, since this may come up for other people who may find this through a Google search for the error message (and the existing results don't apply to this case).

Answer (score 3):

The locale file needs fullcalendar to be present already.

Load the locale file *after* loading fullcalendar itself.

Comment: also be careful when sending up to the server -- for reasons that escape understanding, certain MS browsers insert BiDi characters when locale is applied to a date string and then ASP.NET doesn't recognize the value as a date -- see this fiddle for a regex to remove the characters https://jsfiddle.net/stand__sure/modbaeLf/

Answer (score 0):

i think the full calendar is not called correctly. It expects a setting or options object.

Try calling it inside document ready object, by

```
(function($){
  $(function(){
       // rest of the code here
  })
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: The calendar shows ok when  I get rid off locale settings. I think the problem is another place. It´s a script fault problem.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as my solution was different....

using fullCalendar 3.0.9.2 (latest version as of today), I kept getting the same error

> Cannot read property 'datepickerLocale' of undefined

Making sure the locale file was after the .js didn't help

DOES NOT WORK

```
<script src="path_to_js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="path_to_js/locale-all.js"></script>
```

DOES WORK

```
<script src="path_to_js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="path_to_js/locale-all.js"></script>
```

The difference is in the use of the 'min' version - went to the full version and all looks/works great.

It might also be that I'm using the 'locale-all' file instead of a single one.  Not all combinations tested, though you can't argue with success!